# Trouble adding value to registry key

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'm trying to add a value ("UpdateSvc") under the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` using C++. This is the code used:

```
bool regWrite(LPCSTR subkey, LPCSTR name, DWORD type, const char * value)
{
    HKEY key;

    if (RegCreateKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey, &key) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return false;
    if (RegSetValueExA(key, name, NULL, type, (LPBYTE)value, strlen(value) * sizeof(char) + 1) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return false;
    if (RegCloseKey(key) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool ret;
    ret = regWrite("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "UpdateSvc", REG_SZ, "Test");
    printf("%d", ret);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It prints '1', yet I can't seems to be able to find the value. Tried checking with regedit as well as `reg query HKCU\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run` (including `/reg:32` and `/reg:64` for good measure).

The same thing occurs with

`system("reg add HKCU\\software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\run /v UpdateSvc /t REG_SZ /d Test /f";` (which I know is unsafe, just debugging).

Running 64-bit Visual Studio as Administrator on 64-bit Windows 10. The user I'm logged on to is not an Admin.

## Edit

@IInspectable solved it. The value was added under the administrator's hive, not mine, hence why it wasn't visible.

Comment: You must escape the backslashes in your string, e.g. `Software\\Micros...`

Comment: Didn't your compiler warn about unknown escape sequences? Turn warnings on.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't help.

Comment: Your code works fine with `regWrite("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "UpdateSvc", REG_SZ, "Test")`, but because things may go wrong, error checking is still required as posted in Govind Parmar's answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That won't compile.

Comment: Like so many questions in the winapi tag, your code does not perform any error checking. Don't ignore return values!!

Comment: @MikeDvorkin why? Is compile fine here.

Comment: @IInspectable but there is no redirection for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable my sample in the comment does not use raw strings literals... I removed the first comment.

Comment: The project is set to compile for x64.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it's the comment you removed that didn't work out, what you posted later is fine. I've tried many variations on this but nothing seems to actually create the value in question.

Comment: *"Running Visual Studio as Administrator."* - Where are you looking for the changes in the registry? The current user's hive, or the administrator's?

Comment: @IInspectable Solved it. The value was added under the administrator's hive, not mine, hence why it wasn't visible. Thanks :)

Comment: @IInspectable good catch!! I was really starting to scratch my head. I really should have read the question until the very end.

Comment: @alk how else am I supposed to test functionality that requires administrative privileges? (even though that didn't turn out to be the case here)

Comment: @mik: E.g. by supplying an [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/application-manifests), asking for *autoElevate*. You don't have to run Visual Studio with administrative privileges.

Comment: @IInspectable I see. Is there any way to mark the question as closed?

Comment: Supply an answer, and accept it. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Ideally also update the question, including the information, where you looked for the keys, as well as the bitness of the application and OS. You should also replace the first code example with the second one.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to supply an answer, since the question was put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

The registry functions all return values of type `LSTATUS` indicating whether they succeeded or failed. If `RegCreateKey` fails, `RegSetValueEx` on the `HKEY` value will obviously also fail.  Also, if `RegCloseKey` fails (unlikely) then pending writes may not be flushed to the registry.

```
if(RegCreateKeyA(...) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // Handle error
}
if(RegSetValueExA(...) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that raw string literals are a C feature, so the title is accidentally misleading - this is a C++ project.